# Is it possible to deconstruct and reconstruct a WIX executable?

Tags: powershell, wix

I have a WIX executable install package which for the sake of simplicity lets just call setup.exe. Using a Powershell script I need to do the following with this package:

```
 1. Deconstruct the setup.exe WIX package.
 2. Unpack the setup.msi file contained within.
 3. Modify a config file within the unpacked setup.msi.
 4. Repack setup.msi with this new config.
 5. Reconstruct the setup.exe WIX package.
```

Currently I can do steps 1 to 4 in the following way:

```
1. Run dark.exe -x OutputFolder1 setup.exe.
2. Run ms2xml.exe -c OutputFolder2 setup.msi
3. Update the config file.
4. Run xml2msi.exe -m setup.xml
```

Unfortunately at this point I can't recreate the WIX package using the modified setup.msi even though OutputFolder1 appears to contain all the information that WIX would need to recreate the package.

Therefore is there a way to recreate a WIX package that was deconstructed using dark?  Alternatively is there another way to achieve this without using dark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Light.exe to rebuild a bundle. It can't start from a decompiled bundle.

Comment: Thanks. What files do you need to rebuild the bundle using Light.exe? The install file only contains an msi and a net46 installable.

Comment: All the object files from compiling the bundle, which are linked and bound into the bundle .exe.